# Java Table Drag and Drop (no JTable) get Column

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, jtable, swt

I have a program with two tables, no Jtables, an I want to add drag and drop.
it is nearly working with:

```
public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
    if (TextTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(event.currentDataType)) {
        DropTarget target = (DropTarget) event.widget;
        TableItem item = (TableItem) event.item;
        String data = (String) event.data;
        int col=1;
        item.setText(col,data);
        System.out.println("  DROP:  " + data);
    }   
}
```

With `event.item` I got the right row, but how did I get the right column for "int col" when I released the mouse button?

Comment: Don't you work with @FXML?

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox this is tagged Swing, not JavaFX, so I guess the answer is no.

Comment: Class `TextTransfer` belongs to SWT API, so I think the question is probably wrong tagged.

Comment: So you mean this [`Table`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTable.html)? Your question is very confusing, but it would be less so if you posted a [mcve] (because that would show the imports). Voting to close as 'unclear'.

Comment: sorry, swt not swing, i need only the right column, at the moment it is static with int col=1

Comment: You can use TableItem.getBounds(column) to find the position of each column and match that with the event.

Comment: with getBounds(1).x i recieve the relativ position and not the absolut position like with event.x, nearly the same like table.getLocation().x or table.getBounds().x

Comment: You can convert from display relative to control relative using the `toControl` method of `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

thx to greg-449, so it is working

```
public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
if (TextTransfer.getInstance().isSupportedType(event.currentDataType)) {
    // Get the dropped data
    DropTarget target = (DropTarget) event.widget;
    Table table = (Table) target.getControl();
    TableItem item = (TableItem) event.item;
    String data = calc.KM_DEC_KM_V((String) event.data);
    int col=1;
    Control absolut = getParent().getDisplay().getFocusControl();
    if (item != null){
        col =  getColumn(table,event.x + absolut.toControl(item.getBounds(0).x,item.getBounds(0).y).x);
        if (col==1 || col==2) {
            item.setText(col,data);
        }
    }
    table.redraw();
    System.out.println("  DROP:  " + data);
}   
}
```

with

```
private static int getColumn(Table table, int x)
{
    int overallWidth = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        overallWidth += table.getColumn(i).getWidth();
        System.out.println("overallWidth "+ overallWidth);
        if(x < overallWidth)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```